# Этимология слов "ружье" и "оружие"

Tags: этимология

Задумался: а каково происхождение слов "оружие" и (как мне кажется) производного от него — "ружье"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы правы: современное значение ружьё как один из предметов вооружения - следствие сужения значения слова. "Ружьё" появилось в 17 веке  от "оружие"(вооружение).А "оружие"- от корня ръг - руг (у восточных славян носовой гласный изменился в у).Оружие - это то, чем колют - с тем же корнем, что в слове ругать(бранить), в диалекте ругать - "попирать ногами". Древнерусское оружь-оругjь- "палка, оружие"

Answer (score 6):

Есть предположение, что родственно слову - рог, о-рожие. Палка, с насаженным на нее рогом, становится оружием, которым можно заколоть.

Answer (score 5):

Да, вы обсалютно правы. Слово "ружьё" происходит от "оружие".

> Происходит от народн. формы, связанной
> с соответствующей книжной оружие.
> Форма ружьё «оружие» есть уже в Кн. о
> ратн. строен. (1647 г.), Моск. грам.
> (1676 г.). У Котошихина — еще в знач.
> «оружие».

А этимология "оружия" такова:

> Происходит от праслав. формы, от
> которой в числе прочего произошли:
> ст.-слав. орѫжие (др.-греч. ὅπλον,
> μάχαιρα), др.-русск. оружиıе (при
> исконном русск. ружьё), укр. ору́жжя,
> белор. ружжо́, болг. оръ́жие,
> сербохорв. о̀ру̑жjе, словенск. oróžje,
> rožjè «оружие», чешск. oruží, польск.
> oręż. Сюда же болг. ръ́гам «колю,
> сверлю». Родственно лит. reñgtis,
> rengiúos «снаряжаться», aprangá
> «снаряжение», apreñgti «снабжать,
> снаряжать, одевать», išreñgti
> «снимать, раздевать».

Цитаты из словаря Фасмера.

Comment: Вообще-то, по-украински будет "зброя"

Comment: Возможно, я не знаток укринского. Думаю, Фасмер не с потолка взял своё слово. Быть может, "зброя" синоним к "оружжя"?

Comment: Нет. Слова "оружжя" в украинском просто не существует. Только "зброя".

Comment: оружжя Результатов: примерно 224 000 (0,28 сек.)  (google)
Многовато для несуществующего слова

Муштруйся, рекруте-небоже,  
Слізьми оружжя обливай!   
Хились, корись, а тільки, брате,  
Оружжя з рук не випускай!   
(з Iвана Франка)

Для сильной армії своєї  
Рушниць, мушкетів, оружжин  
Наклали повні гамазеї,  
Гвинтівок, фузій без пружин,  
Булдимок, флинт і яничарок.  
....  
Сказав, і військо загриміло,  
Як громом, разним оружжям;  
Построїлось і полетіло  
Простесенько к градським стінам.  
(Котляревськiй, "Енеїда" - обожаю!)

Comment: Снаряжение и оружие вряд ли однокоренные. У снаряжения явно корень ряд, рядить, снаряжать. Снаряжение это то, что надевают на себя, снаряжаются.
А оружие это то, что наносит поражение - разит.

Comment: Поэты иногда употребляли русские слова для рифмы или ритма. Я все-таки носитель языка и немного знаю, какие украинские слова литературные, а какие нет.

Comment: Fuchoin Kazuki и Behemothus, вы, каждый по-своему, правы.
Современный диктор на украинском ТВ скажет, скорее всего, *зброя*. Правда, этот вопрос сильно заполитизирован и дикторы, особенно на канале СТБ иногда такое чудят...

Если сравнить с русским языком, то диктор росс. ТВ вряд ли будет говорить: *ложить, коих, зело, написать прошение, премьер-министр милостиво повелеть соизволил*... :-) Надеюсь, сравнение понятное!

Есть понятие **современного литературного** украинского языка. Подчёркиваю, **современного** и **литературного**.

Comment: По поводу уважаемого Котляревского (спасибо за цитату! с удовольствием прочитал!). Язык, лексика, Пушкина, к примеру, отличается от того, как говорят на современном ТВ, возможно, к сожалению.

Практически все те слова, которые написаны в приведённом отрывке, употребляются в **разговорной** речи и на современной Полтавщине (откуда Котляревский), и в других местах. Кроме, пожалуй, слова "градським". Скажут: "городським" (разг., но очень распространённое слово) или "мiським". А для Хорватии вполне нормальное слово.

Comment: Можно много спорить о нормах в совр. украинском, и много спорят об этом -- доказывают, что что-то искусственное, что-то не народное. Но, вот не поленюсь для образца переписать приведённый отрывок Котляревского *по-современному*. Хуже это или лучше -- отдельный вопрос.

Сказав, і військо загриміло,  
Як громом, р**і**зною зброєю;  
Вишикувало**ся** і полетіло  
Простесенько (скорее скажут "прямісінько") **до** міських стін.

Обратите внимание, если интересно, на выделенное жирным жрифтом. Не "к", а "до" и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

***to Fuchoin Kazuki***

> Нет. Слова "оружжя" в украинском просто не существует. Только "зброя".

Ну,как безаппеляционно!Не читали оригинальную литературу,наверное. А верить украинским словарям нельзя, они меняются с изменением направления политического ветра.Пользуйтесь первоисточниками и помните: весь проект "Украина" - дело временное, значит возможно ВСЁ!

> Словник української мови
> Академічний тлумачний словник (1970—1980)

```
       в означеннях
```

> Тлумачення, значення слова «оружжя»:
> ОРУЖЖЯ, я, сер., розм., заст. Зброя.
> Єдиним оружжям Остаповим була вода, і він од часу до часу обливав нею вовка, не допускаючи до себе (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 300);
> Розповів [парубок], що на всіх дорогах війська видимо-невидимо. Припас везуть і оружжя (Панас Кочура, Зол. грамота, 1960, 5).

Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 5, 1974. — Стор. 751.

Comment: Может быть, не будем хамить администрации, а? Конечно же, администратор форума по языку не читал классику и вообще не разбирается в предмете. Угу.  
Вам бы я советовала почитать *оригинальную литературу* по культуре поведения, если родители в детстве не воспитали.

Comment: Пардон, за неуместный,может быть, совет. Но, Ваше ***Только "зброя"*** просто возмутило.

Comment: Статус администратора - это слишком мало, чтобы отмахиваться от фактов, которые вам предоставили. Извините, что вмешался.

Comment: Гы... "Мультовкие войны, Еpisode III. Статусы и факты."

Comment: Избавьте меня от подобных колкостей. Они хоть и безосновательны, но по-человечески неприятно.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на правду то, что **оружие** происходит от **рог**, ибо для животного с рогами, они - оружие. Но вот рог может происходить от ругаться, т.к. при бодании животные издают звуки, похожие на ругань, а из этих звуков наши предки спокойно могли создать такие слова, как рог и ругань. Кстати, в белорусском языке есть слово **ружа** - **роза**, шипы которой напоминают маленькие **рожки**.

Answer (score 0):

У древних славян основным боевым оружием было копье. Некий наконечник, соединенный с рожном (палкой). Отсюда - "лезть на рожон". Вооружиться значит взять в руки копье.

Answer (score -1):

Пример Ивана Франко не очень удачен. В современном ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМ украинском языке слова "оружжя" нет. На (опять же повторюсь) современном литературном украинском языке русское слово "оружие" будет "зброя"

Comment: Можете повторять сколько угодно. Академический словарь(Украинский) с Вами не согласен. Хотя "ОРУЖЖЯ" дается с пометкой "заст" и "розм"(устар.разг. - по русски), полонизированная "зброя"("вооруженный" - по польски "uzbrojony") утвердилась в словарях и преподавании только потому,что меньше похоже на русский язык, как и многое другое.К тому же и Франко, и Кочура, и Коцюбинский, и Котляревский - все же основоположники ЛИТЕРАТУРНОГО языка, авторитеты,а не @Vadim какой-то.

Comment: Я не собираюсь обсуждать тонкости использования слова, но фраза "В современном ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМ украинском языке слова" слишком безапелляционна. Слово может устареть, но **исчезнуть** за дести даже лет из языка совершенно - это фантастика.  
Да и словари, как уже сказали не раз, не на вашей стороне.

Comment: to @behemothus.Да современному украинскому языку даже с большой натяжкой двести лет не наберется.Невообразимый успех Котляревского с Энеидой, Наталкой и проч.впервые породил мнение,что на малороссийскм наречии можно ПИСАТЬ.

Comment: Первое заграничное издание на "русинском" наречии(слово УКРАИНСКИЙ в этнич.смысле до второй половины 19 века не найдете,Шевченко,к примеру, в своем письменном наследии - всём - ни разу не использовал слово УКРАИНЕЦ) - это руський альманах "Русалка Днѣстровая", для которой изобретался специальная система письма, изданный так называемой "руськой троицей"-москвофильским сообществом Шашкевича, Головацкого и Могилевича в Буде,Австро-Венгрия.

Comment: Ну Котляревскому-то больше двухсот лет. Я от него и отсчитывал, поскольку цитаты были из Энеиды.

Comment: Шановні друзі! Я не бачу сенсу сперечатися :)
Розмовляючи українською, ви можете вживати  слова, що вам заманеться :).... "оружжя" замість "зброя", "райдуга" замість "веселка", "кип'яток" замість "окріп" тощо...  :)
Це ваша особиста справа

Comment: "Людская МОЛВЬ и конский ТОП","ЦЫГАНЫ" (А.С.Пушкин)
"Из ПЛАМЯ и света" (М.Ю.Лермонтов)
"Нежные!Вы любовь на скрипки ЛОЖИТЕ. Любовь на литавры ЛОЖИТ грубый..." (В.В. Маяковский)
" А на левой стороне - ИХНИЕ посты..." (В.С.Высоцкий)
_____________________________________________________
Сразу говорю, что очень люблю всех вышеперечисленных авторов. И не только их :)
А теперь просто вопрос:
Должен ли преподаватель русского языка снижать оценку за употребление выделенных мной слов именно в таком виде, если это НЕ ЦИТАТЫ ?
Точно так же и со словом "оружжя" в украинском языке ...  :)

Comment: Если Вы создаете художественное произведение, сочинение, например, на вольную тему, можете употреблять и пафосные, и церковные слова,и церковные выражения, особым образом окрашивающие ваше произведения, и стилизованные под просторечие обороты, если они органичны в Вашем произведении, а не притянуты за уши, как в современной украинской речи "міліціянты", "автівки" и другие галицизмы или выхваченные из эмигрантских наречий модные словечки. Кроме того, я же не утверждаю, что слово "зброя" незаконно.Я защищаю слово "оружжя" как законный синоним.

Comment: Я не против того, что Вы защищаете, но, боюсь, что современные украинские филологи не согласятся с Вами. И вряд ли признают слово "оружжя" синонимом слова "зброя". Правы они или нет - это уже другой вопрос :)
И вообще, мой вопрос был о другом. 
Да и тема сама об этимологии слов "ружьё" и "оружие" как слов русского языка.

Comment: Вы правы,behemothus,но язык Котляревского еще очень далек от литературного. Котляревский создавал свои творения для русской широкой публики, в просветительских,думаю,целях.Жители Малороссии не ездили в Петербург и Москву посмотреть "Наталку Полтавку", зато местная публика валила валом.И "Энеиду" большинство будущих украинцев тогда не читали, это была забава для образованных людей, а образование тогда в тех краях было либо польским, либо русским. Шевченко свой "Букварь южнорусский" создавал на полвека позднее, это было его последнее дело, но первый шаг к образованию на украинском языке.

Answer (score -1):

Слово *оружие* произошло от формы "оручие", то есть прикреплённое к руке. По аналогии: *нож* — от "оножье", нечто носимое при ноге. Сибиряки меня поймут (и не надо усложнять).

Comment: Что за форма "оручие", и почему прикреплённое? Есть ссылка? И что такого должны понять сибиряки, а другим понимать и не надо?